# Xamarin bindable property never gets set

Tags: c#, xamarin

**MyCustomRenderer.cs** (the setter here never gets hit)

```
public class MyGrid : Grid
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ItemSource", typeof(Cat), typeof(MyGrid), null);
    public Cat ItemSource
    {
        get { return (Cat)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
    }
    ...
}
```

**MyPage.xaml** (here is how the CustomRenderer is being used)

```
...
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ViewModels:MyViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
...
<CustomRenderers:MyGrid ItemSource="{Binding TheCat}" />
...
```

**MyViewModel.cs** (Here's the view model)

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Cat _cat;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Cat TheCat {
        get { return _cat; }
        set {
            _cat = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TheCat"));
        }
    }
}
```

**MyPage.xaml.cs** (here's where it all starts; this is where we set TheCat)

```
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public ComparisonPage (Cat theCat)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        var viewModel = (MyViewModel)BindingContext;
        viewModel.TheCat = theCat;
    }
}
```

I had a similiar version of this code working just fine. The only difference I can think of instead of passing around a `Cat` I was passing around an `ObservableCollection<Cat>`. I could be missing something else though.

I think what should happen is:

1. **MyPage.xaml.cs** sets TheCat
2. **MyViewMode.cs** handle setting TheCat, raises change event if anyone is listening.
3. **MyPage.xaml** binds TheCat to **MyCustomRenderer.cs**, which *is* listening.
4. The setter for `ItemSource` in **MyCustomRenderer.cs** finally gets hit.

But by stepping through those steps it seems to stop somewhere around step 2. Am I missing something obvious here? AFAICT it should work.

Comment: For starters in your bindable property `typeof(ComparisonTable)` should be `typeof(MyGrid)`. Also, instead of manually typing the string values I'd use `nameof(ItemSource)`

Comment: That was just a typo. It's fixed in the example now. I agree with your opinion and in fact am doing it that way in the actual code. Any idea on why it's not working?

Comment: For the most part then your `BindableProperty` looks correct. I guess the question is what is `MyGrid` doing with the `ItemSource` property because you may need to overload `propertyChanged` on your `BindableProperty`. Also, it might be worth it to try setting the BindingContext on `MyGrid` from code and to see if for some reason it isn't getting the binding context from your xaml.

Comment: I'm not going to list this as the answer because there's still too much I don't know. It works if I move `<ContentPage.BindingContext><ViewModels:MyViewModel /></ContentPage.BindingContext>` into the code behind. e.g. `var viewModel = new MyViewModel() { TheCat=theCat }; InitializeComponent();`

Comment: If that works then it does look like you need to add a propertyChanged method to your `ItemSource` and do whatever you are doing with `TheCat`, like I'm assuming you might be doing in `MyGrid` ctor or somewhere, and do it in that method as well. If you provide more of your `MyGrid` class I could explain exactly why.